# Use RDS/Terminal Server Gateway to access remote servers

Tags: rdp, cloud, remote-desktop-gateway

We have a number of Windows servers in the cloud. Due to specifics of our network setup, we cannot RDP to those servers directly from our network.  We have a separate data centre with a private link, from which we can RDP to those servers in the cloud.

A simple (technical) solution is to set up a server in that separate data centre; the users would RDP into that "jump" server, then from there RDP to the servers in the cloud.  This is not simple from the user convenience point of view, especially to copy files.

I was investigating a TS Gateway/RDS as a possible solution.  On the surface of it, it looks exactly like what I want, however all the documentation I'm reading talks about using it to connect to other servers within the same network.  Is it possible to use it as the gateway "proxy" to connect to servers outside of the network where this TSG is installed?

Yes, I can try setting it all up, however before I commit team resources to it (setting up server, local network, BGP, firewall rules, etc.) I hope to get at least the notional "yes it's possible" or "no way, don't even try".

Comment: An RD gateway can front end an RDP session to a host anywhere in the world. I've seen it used as a front end for connecting to all desktops in a global company. Not usually selected for convenience though.

Comment: The features of an RDG that most select for are: front end for multiple farms; native smart card support; works over https tcp/443; ability to create security groupings for access to resources, with granular device control (deny drive/clipboard redirection). The session is still routed through the data center.